# Unable to connect to the internet from freshly installed OS

Tags: 12.04

I have been a windows XP user so far. I have freshly installed ubuntu 12.04.4 om my flash drive and am booting my dell vostro 1015 from this usb device. Wifi network works perfectly fine with XP but do not show up on ubuntu. It always says wireless network disconnected because Broadcom STA is not activated. When I try to do that from additional drivers it gets stuck. It takes forever giving the message downloading and installing but there is no end. The window does not close by clicking on X nor does Cancel work even on repeated clicks. I finally had to shut the system down in middle of the process. I know similar questions have been asked but none of them solved my problem. I tried the lspci command as well as dmseg and couple of more but I do not understand what they mean. Please help me somebody, please.

Answer (score 0):

I am not a guru, but, may I suggest two things that might help?

1) Perhaps trying to install an official variant of Ubuntu such as Lubuntu or Xubuntu (both carry the official Ubuntu software center) is an option. Ubuntu might require grander resources than your current machine can offer.

2) Plug into LAN from the beginning of the installation. Upon the start, make sure you select to have additional drivers and updates done while the progress takes place.

I sincerely hope this helps in some way.

Juan

Comment: Should I install the versions you suggested by formatting my flash drive again? I guess I have these versions from the official site. Also when I type lspci -vvnn | grep 14e4, it tells that my chip ID is BCM4312 802.11b/g and the PCI ID is  [14e4:4315]. I typed in  sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source, it then says the driver is installed and broadcom too installed. But wifi networks aren't showed still. I also restarted my computer and was back to square one with no driver installed. But thanks anyway I'll try your suggestion and hope it works this time.

Comment: I wish I could answer the more technical questions, But I am unable to provide you with accurate responses. I hope the community could chip in at this point. However, I still hope you can resolve this issue. Also, if you were to install the variants, then you should re-format the usb installer since the variant would require so.